# Create running number animation with decimals

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to crate an animation which animates a decimal number from startNumber to endNumber. What I have is this:

```
string resultPoints = ""; // The result of the animation

float startPoints = 0f; // From what point should we start
float endPoints = 79.57f; // End points
float rNo = startPoints;
float wTime = 0.01f;

wTime = 1f / (endPoints - startPoints);

endPoints++;

while (rNo < endPoints)
{
    resultPoints = "" + rNo;
    rNo++;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(wTime);
}
```

This do the animation, but only with whole numbers (integer). How do I create this function with decimals?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: The `++` operator only ever adds 1 as an integer.  That's it.  If you want to increment by something smaller then do it manually with `rNo = rNo + .1`?  ... or `+ .01`, etc...

Comment: Or `rNo += 0.1`.